# Zend_Amf and Actionscript 2

Tags: zend-framework, amf

Anyone know if Zend_Amf (1.9) can talk to Actionscript 2 which uses the Amf0 specification? All the examples in the Zend docs are for Actionscript 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can. I got it working using mx.remoting.